# Corsets, movie sets and assets

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> My prefix prefix does exhilarating kicks,
>   My infix infix uncovered the wizard's tricks,
>   My suffix suffix is quieter than a tick,
>   Gone a century since, he made infinite picks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Cantor

My prefix prefix does exhilarating kicks,

> [**Can-can**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can-can)

My infix infix uncovered the wizard's tricks,

> **Toto** pulls the curtain in The Wizard of Oz.

My suffix suffix is quieter than a tick,

> [RR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate#Electronic_measurement)? Or possibly  [RR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_rate) 
>  **Edit:** As mentioned by Tom, this instead refers to a [Rolls Royce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Motor_Cars) vehicle for which the loudest noise comes from the tick of the electric clock.

Gone a century since, he made infinite picks.

> Cantor. 
>  His diagonalisation argument involves making infinite picks, plus he died in 1918. 
>  **Edit:** As suggested by Bass in the comments, the infinite picks could refer to the process of generating the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)

Comment: Judging from the title, the infinite pickings could refer to [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: This has settled it. For the third line I was going for the car of which there is a saying that the loudest noise comes from the electric clock. Nice alt from Bass.

Comment: Each word in the title alludes to something associated with the corresponding clued word. If @Tom were looking for suggestions, "Corsets, movie sets, assets and his sets" would clue the final word as well. ;-)